# 503 Error when invoking WebMethod C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013

So i'm relatively new to making WebServices so please bear with me.

I made on a server a Webservice with a simple helloword webmethod and then deployed it in IIS 7.5.

When calling the ' .*asmx* ' file in my browser on the server, I can see all the webmethods and I can invoke them.

Than I made a client application where i added my webservices through the " Add data source " in Visual Studio 2013, that was no problem it saw all my webmethods.

But when I tried to call my webservice in the code and tried invoking my webmethod it's giving me an exception.

```
Additional information: The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at WebserviceConnection.WebReference.WebService1.HelloWorld() in c:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebserviceConnection\WebserviceConnection\Web References\WebReference\Reference.cs:line 78
   at WebserviceConnection.Form1..ctor() in c:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebserviceConnection\WebserviceConnection\Form1.cs:line 21
```

When i made the same application on my server where the webservice is running on there were no problems at all.

So i've tried the following things already:
- I check my application pool in IIS, whether it was down or not. 
- Check the logs, and i can't find anything definite on why it's not working.

I can btw call my webservice in the browser on any computer i want, it's only giving me this error when invoking the webmethod in my C# application.

Client C# Code:

```
namespace ConsumeWebserviceTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebService1 te = new WebService1();
            label1.Text = te.HelloWorld();
        }
    }
}
```

Webservice code:

```
namespace WebServiceTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Im running on .NET Framework 4.0, So i'm wondering why it's giving me this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `503` means

**503 Service Unavailable**
`The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.`

**My Suggestion: Please check server name and it's IIS is running or not**

For more Http Status [**Refer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: The IIS Server is running, because i can still call my webservice in a browser on any computer i want, and that works fine.

Comment: It's means Integration is not proper, please check